# Multiple for loops in puppeteer js for a dynamic drop down scrape

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Currently I'm scraping a web page that has multiple drop downs and each drop down is dependent on a parent drop down.

I have three variables which give me the length of each drop down.

```
sizeLength, turnaroundLength, quantityLength
```

sizeLength = 32, turanroundlength = 2, quantityLength = 30

I first need to set sizeLength to 1 and then after that turnaround length to 1 and then I need to loop through each quantity Length which is 30 total.

To achieve this I did some nested for loops:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= sizeLength; i++) {

  await page.evaluate( () => {
    document.querySelector( '#size > option:nth-child('+i+')' ).selected = true} );

  for (let x = 1; x <= turnaroundLength; x++) {

    await page.evaluate( () => {
      document.querySelector( '#turnaround > option:nth-child('+x+')' ).selected = true} );
  }

    for (let y = 1; y <= quantityLength; y++) {

      await page.evaluate( () => {
        document.querySelector( '#quantity > option:nth-child('+y+')' ).selected = true} );
    }
    console.log('this is in quantity');
    }

}
```

Using this method I get an error: await is only valid in async function.
I'm not sure how to work around this as I'm new to puppeteer.  Any advice would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) operator is used to wait for a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), and **it can only be used inside an** [`async function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

The Puppeteer function [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) returns a promise, so you must wait for the promise to [`resolve`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) or [`reject`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject) before continuing the next iteration of your loop.

As a result, you must wrap your code in an async function for the code to work properly.

Additionally, as your loops are now written, you will not achieve the behavior you are expecting because the counters are not being passed to `page.evaluate()`.

Your code should look something like this instead:

```
( async () =>
{
    const sizeLength       = 32;
    const turanroundlength = 2;
    const quantityLength   = 30;

    for ( let i = 1; i <= sizeLength; i++ )
    {
        await page.evaluate( i =>
        {
            document.querySelector( '#size > option:nth-child(' + i + ')' ).selected = true;

        }, i );

        for ( let x = 1; x <= turnaroundLength; x++ )
        {
            await page.evaluate( x =>
            {
                document.querySelector( '#turnaround > option:nth-child(' + x + ')' ).selected = true;

            }, x );
        }

        for ( let y = 1; y <= quantityLength; y++ )
        {
            await page.evaluate( y =>
            {
                document.querySelector( '#quantity > option:nth-child(' + y + ')' ).selected = true;

            }, y );
        }

        console.log( 'this is in quantity' );
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thank you @Grant Miller... Extra points for the scripture on your profile!